# What else is a neighbourhood?

Tags: general-topology, definition

I need to settle an argument.

Yes or no:

If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space ($X$ is an arbitrary - and I mean *arbitrary* - set, $\tau\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ is the collection of open sets), then a set $N$ is a neighbourhood of a point $x\in X$ iff there exists an open set $U\in\tau$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\subseteq N$.

In short: a neighbourhood is a superset of an open set.

If no, then what am I missing? My friend seems to think that there is something special about neighbourhoods that cannot be explained in such basic terms. I think that my friend is still holding onto the idea that "topology" means "metric topology."

Comment: This is not clear.  Neighborhood of what?  Neighborhoods are generally defined with reference to a particular point in the set.

Comment: To stress: If all you are saying is that a neighborhood of a point $x\in X$ is any subset of $X$ that contains some open subset of $X$ which also contains $x$, then that is indeed the usual definition.  If you think you are saying something other than that, you should clarify.

Comment: @lulu No, that is exactly what I'm saying. That's why I don't understand why my friend keeps going back to a neighbourhood of $x$ containing points "at most some distance" from an open set containing $x$.

Comment: There is no notion of distance in a topological space. You are right.

Comment: There is no notion of "distance" in a general topological space.

Comment: I think it depends on the authors notation, I would say that that is a neighborhood, but most of the time you just want an open neighborhood

Comment: The definition that you stated is the same definition in general topology by Willard. So, nhood can be even closed set. In topology by Munkers it defines like "any open set contains $x$ is called a nhood.

Comment: Some authors use neighbourhood to mean an open set, some mean it to be any set containing a (suitable) open set.

Comment: distance gives a topology but topologies can be defined without a notion of distance at all.

Comment: Your friend seems to be using their intuition for metric spaces, which are spaces with a notion of distance (called the metric). As other people mentioned above, not all topological spaces are metric spaces, and no matter how hard you try you cannot put a metric on some of them (these are called *non-metrisable*). So while your friend's idea is not wrong, it only works in the case for metric spaces, not the general topological space context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is certainly very common and well-established.

But some authors insist that a neighbourhood of $x$ is an *open* set that contains $x$. I usually call that "open neighbourhood" instead. IMO a less useful definition.

In a metric space $(X,d)$ (in the induced topology) your definition (which I also prefer, because it allows me to talk about closed and compact neighbourhoods as well, without being restricted by openness requirements) is just equivalent to saying that $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ iff there is some $r>0$ so that $B_d(x,r) \subseteq N$ and this is a very common first definition in many analysis courses, I believe. But a metric space is just a very special topological space anyway (maybe not as your friend sees it, but it *is*.). The metric definition is just a special case of the definition you gave.

As long as it's clear if you're working in a general (topological) space or a metric space, you and your friend will have no need to quarrel.

Comment: You're right. I really do wish that people would stop introducing topology via metric spaces. I mean, *almost every* topological space is non-metrisable, so using metric spaces as a "typical" example is basically lying.